# Append data to same text file using java

Tags: java

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmSS");
   String strCurrDate = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
   String strfileNm = "Customer_" + strCurrDate + ".txt";
   String strFileGenLoc = strFileLocation + "/" + strfileNm;
   String Query1="select '0'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')||'123456789' class_code from   dual";
   String Query2="select '0'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')||'123456789' class_code from   dual";
   String Query3="select param from dual"; 
  try {
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  Statement stmt1 = null;
  ResultSet rs1 = null;

     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
     stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query1);
     rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(Query2);
     rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(Query3);

 File f = new File(strFileGenLoc);
 OutputStream os = (OutputStream)new FileOutputStream(f,true);
 String encoding = "UTF8";
 OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, encoding);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

 while (rs.next() ) {

     bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));
     bw.write("  ");


 }
 bw.flush();
 bw.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(
     "Exception occured while getting resultset by the query");
 e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
 try {
     if (conn != null) {
         System.out.println("Closing the connection" + conn);
         conn.close();
     }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
     System.out.println(
         "Exception occured while closing the connection");
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
     return objArrayListValue;
}

    The above code is working fine. it writes the content of "rs" resultset data in  text file

   Now what i want is ,i need to append the 


   the content in "rs2" resultset to the "same text file"(ie . i need to append "rs2"  content with "rs" content in the same text file)..

   ------------------edit part----------------

     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
     stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query1);
     rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(Query2);
     rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(Query3);


     while ( rs.next() ) {

     while(rs1.next()){

          while(rs2.next()){

     bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));
         bw.write("\t");
     bw.write(rs1.getString(1)==null? "":rs1.getString(1));
     bw.write("\t");
     bw.write(rs2.getString(1)==null? "":rs2.getString(1));
     bw.write("\t");

     bw.newLine();

          }
     }
 }
```

Above code working fine.
My problem is

1. "rs" resultset contains one record in the table
2. "rs1" resultset contains 5 record in the table
3. "rs2" resultset contains 5 record in the table

"rs" data is getting recursive.

while writing to the same text file , the output i am getting  like

```
1   2    3
1   12   21
1   23   25
1   10   5
1   8    54
```

but i need output like below

```
1   2    3
   12   21
   23   25
   10   5
    8    54
```

What things i need to change in my code.. Please advice

```
    -----------------edit part1------------------


      Expected Result is 

            1   2    3
            1   12   21
            1   23   25
            1   10   5
            1   8    54

   but output i got like

            1   2    3
            12   21
            23   25
            10   5
             8    54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new FileOutputStream(f,true);
```

You have already set the append flag to true(the second argument), so do the same as what you did with the previous result set.

See: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: No probs. Although I mistakenly added a link to FileWriter object instead of your suggested FileOutputStream. My answer (which I removed since it was similar to yours) contained a FileWriter link...

Comment: wheather i need to do any modification here ?
"rs" result set contains one data and "rs1" resultset contains 10 data.how to loop "rs2" here.

please reply ASAP..Its urgent..


while (rs.next() ) {


     bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));
     bw.write("  ");


 }

Comment: And I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: @PetarMinChev ...Please see the Edit part in source program

Comment: So you want the results grouped by rs?

Comment: If it is so, move these two lines "bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));" and "bw.write("\t");" immediately after "while ( rs.next() ) {"

Comment: What do you mean? If it is only that there is not a tab at the beginning, you can solve it easily.

Comment: See your edit, you are contradicting yourself on the expected result.